# Error ejecutando Genexus: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo.

Tags: java, genexus, web

Cuando intento compilar cualquier objeto, al final siempre devuelve el siguiente error. He notado que se genera el objeto en la carpeta `Models` pero NO en la `webapps`. Ya he probado de hacer `Rebuild all` y sucede lo mismo. No sé qué más hacer.

```
========== Build With This Only started ==========
========== Target Environment update started ==========
Target Environment update Success
Building changed objects list
========== Specification started ==========
Generating messages for Spanish ...
Generating messages for English ...
Generators messages generated.
Specifying EnviarCorreoNoReply (1 of 1) ...
Specifying stub EnviarCorreoNoReply ...
Specification Success
========== Generation started ==========
Generating Resources...Success
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\aenviarcorreonoreply.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\enviarcorreonoreply.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\SdtMessages_Message.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\StructSdtMessages_Message.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\gxcfg.js
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\GXcfg.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\client.cfg
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\bld12.info
Generating to sm12_4.ari
Compressing static files...Success
Generation Success
File 'upload.jar' copied to "C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\web\drivers\upload.jar"
========== EnviarCorreoNoReply Compilation started ==========
callmake.bat "C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\web\GXJMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javac.exe" aenviarcorreonoreply options: -O
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
El ¡ndice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tama¤o de la colecci¢n.
Nombre del par metro: index
Build failed.
EnviarCorreoNoReply Compilation Failed
Build With This Only Failed
```

Si corro el `GXJMake` manuealmente, también sucede lo mismo:

```
C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\web>GXJMake -f home.mak
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e    inferior al tamaño de la colección.
Nombre del parámetro: index
Build failed.
```

Mis conocimientos fuera de `Genexus` son muy limitados, por lo cual les ruego que me ayuden lo antes posible por lo menos a detectar quién es que está tirando este error, pues no sé hacerlo.

Comment: Es necesario que añadas el código que te da error para que podamos ayudarte, pero por si acaso, los indices de los array en Genexus empiezan por 1 en vez de por 0.¿Puede ser que sea esto lo que te esta pasando?

Comment: Hola Fernando, gracias por tu comentario. Te cuento que no puedo pegar el código, pues no tengo idea cual es el objeto que está causando dicho error. Como explico al comienzo, este error me ocurre sea cual sea el objeto que intente compilar. De todas formas, revisé y vi que en todos los objetos que uso alguna variable _&index_ para recorrer una colección, esta es un _Numeric(4.0)_ y se inicializa en 1. ¿Está bien que sea así?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, luego de probar varias cosas sin suerte, finalmente logré resolver el problema.

Lo que hice fue eliminar **todos** los archivos **.ari** de la carpeta **C:\Models\abc\ y sus subcarpetas**, y no solo de la carpeta **C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\state**, lo cual ya había probado antes y sin suerte.

Espero que sea de ayuda si a alguien más le comienza a suceder lo mismo.